# Canonical isomorphism between $V$ vector space and its second dual $V^{\circ \circ}$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

I came a across this when I was reading some book. It says let $V$ a finite dimensional vector space of some field and there is a canonical isomorphism $\phi$ between $V$ and $V^{\circ \circ}$ but didn't specify what it is. Can anyone explain what it is to me?

Comment: Finite dimension? The infinite case is true only for Reflexive spaces.

Comment: @DiegoMath yes it is finite dimension vector space. I am sorry I forgot to mention this condition. I have edited it.

Comment: @WillJagy Remember that for finite dimension there exists a isomorphism between the weak topology and the strong one.

Comment: @Victor I assume from the notation $V^{\circ \circ}$ that you means the second dual, and I changed the title accordingly. If this is wrong, please revert the change.

Comment: Victor are talking about the first or the second dual? If was the first I guees the apropriate notation is $V^*$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming it's a finite dimensional vector space (since it's not true in infinite dimensions). How do we think of elements of $V^{**}$? They are linear functionals on $V^*$, i.e. if $\widehat{x}\in V^{**}$ and $f\in V^*$, then $\widehat{x}(f) \in \mathbb F$.

We want in some way to relate $\widehat{x}$ to something in $V$. What is the natural way to do this? Let's think of it the opposite way: how can we look at an element of $V$ as an element of $V^{**}$? If $x\in V$ and $f\in V^*$, then $f(x) \in \Bbb F$. In some sense we could view $x$ as acting on $f$ by the map $f\mapsto f(x)$. Thus we have that $x$ defines an element of $V^{**}$ by the map $f\mapsto f(x)$. We can therefore embed $V$ into $V^{**}$ by the map $\widehat{x}(f) = f(x)$.

So how is this a *natural* isomorphism? Well we know that for finite dimensional vector spaces, $V^*$ and $V$ have the same dimension, so $V^{**}$ and $V$ have the same dimension so they are isomorphic as vector spaces. The only question is how it is canonical (or natural). I can't say it any better than others have (or any briefer). [See here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/579739/why-it-is-important-for-isomorphism-between-vector-space-and-its-double-dual-spa)

Comment: thanks i think i have got the idea

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is a linear functional, $\phi(x)(f) = f(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

For every $v\in V$, we will assign a linear map that takes a functional as input and outputs an element of the field. If $\phi$ is a functional, then send $v\to\psi_v$, where $\psi_v$ is defined by $\psi_v(\phi)=\phi(v)$. You can check that $\phi_v$ is a linear map from $V^*\to F$, and that the map $v\to\psi_v$ gives an isomorphism $V\to V^{**}$.