# What is so special about natural isomorphism?

Tags: geometry, category-theory

We know that all finite dimensional vector spaces of the same dimension are isomorphic. In particular, if $V$ is of finite dimension, then $(\star)$$V^{**} \cong V \cong V^{*}$. However, we know that these spaces, although isomorphic, are not quite the same. In geometry, for example, one sees huge differences between the space of "vectors" $V$ and the space of "covectors" $V^{*}$. Basically they act in a different manner under a change of coordinates. The spaces $V, V^{**}, \ldots, V^{2*}, \ldots$ all act alike; the spaces $V^{*}, \ldots, V^{(2*)*}, \ldots$ also act alike, but in a different manner from the first group. The only explanation I seem to find for this fact is that, whilst the first isomorphism in $(\star)$ is natural, in a categorical way, the second isn't (not that I can prove that, but I heard it so many times that I decided to belive in it. Anyway, definitely not the point here). The question thus is: what is so special about natural isomorphisms that differentiates spaces from their duals but make them basically the same as their double duals? How can the existence of a natural transformation between functors create so much weirdness?

Comment: A 'natural' isomorphism is a morphism that commutes with 'chaging the space'. Which means that since the double dual commutes with changing our base vector space: we know though that if we're working with fixed dimension, the only change you can make to your space is a base change. Thus, a natural iso in this case is an iso that doesn't depends on the coordinates. The assignment $\epsilon_i( e_j) = \delta_{ij}$, for the basis of the dual, is very basis dependent, thus not natural.

Comment: It basically means that the isomorphism $V \cong V^{**}$ doesn't depend on the choice of coordinates, whereas the isomorphism $V \cong V^*$ does; if you want to talk in physics-y terms.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/579888/400 might be an answer to your question.