# How exactly do natural transformations relate to independence of choice of basis?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, category-theory

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over some field $K$. When I did not know anything about category theory, I learned about an isomorphism $(V^*)^* \cong V$ that 'does not depend on choice of basis', namely the map that sends a vector $v \in V$ to the element in $(V^*)^*$ that sends a functional $\omega$ to $\omega(v)$.

When I learned about category theory, I was told that what this means in a precise sense is that the identity functor is naturally isomorphic to the double dual functor. Now I know exactly what this means, I can intuitively see that a natural isomorphism between two functors means that they 'do the same' in a very strict sense.

However, I do not understand intuitively why this natural isomorphism makes precise the notion of the isomorphism $V \cong V^*$ not being dependent of a choice of basis of $V$.

In short: what do natural isomorphisms have to do with independence of choice of basis? I am sorry for the vague question, I hope it is legitimate and understandable.

Comment: An explanation is given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_transformation#Example:_dual_of_a_finite-dimensional_vector_space), see if that makes sense to you.

Comment: where exactly in the wikipedia page is it being explained?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/579888/400 might answer your question

Comment: There's a section titled "Example: dual of a finite dimensional vector space"