# Natural isomorphism between a vector space and its double dual

Tags: linear-algebra, dual-spaces

The usual way of showing the natural isomorphism between a vector space and its double dual is to prove that the map from $V$ to $V^{**}$ is injective and linear. And since $\dim V = \dim V^*$ and $\dim V^*=\dim V^{**}$, it follows that $\dim V = \dim V^{**}$, which establishes the bijection. I read that showing this isomorphism doesn't require us to choose a basis.

But I've also read that the proof of $\dim V^*=\dim V^{**}$ is similar to $\dim V = \dim V^*$, and proving the latter does require us to choose a basis. So won't establishing that $\dim V^*=\dim V^{**}$ (and hence, in effect, that $\dim V = \dim V^{**}$) also require a choice of basis? That way the proof of the isomorphism requires us to choose a basis at one point, so why is it called a natural isomorphism? Is there supposed to be a basis-free way of showing that $\dim V = \dim V^{**}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I read that showing this isomorphism doesn't require us to choose a basis.

This sentence is a little bit vague. What you probably read is that *defining* the isomorphism doesn't require a choice of basis. You can always define $\phi : V \to V^{**}$ by $\phi(v)(f) = f(v)$.

However, you cannot prove that it is a bijection without involving a basis *somehow*. Since $\phi$ is (in general) only an isomorphism when $V$ is finite-dimensional, you need to use this fact in your argument somewhere, and the dimensionality of a vector space is ultimately defined in terms of the cardinality of a basis for it.

Answer (score 2):

> why is it called a natural isomorphism?

In the category of finite dimensional vector spaces, there is a natural isomorphism of the identity functor to the double-dual functor.  The resulting isomorphism for each object in the category is called "natural" because it is a component of this natural isomorphism of functors. (See [Leinster, Tom. Basic category theory. Vol. 143. Cambridge University Press, 2014](https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.09375) example 1.3.14)

Actually, I need to reframe what I'm saying above.  What is really the case is that mathematicians were aware of such things long before category theory, and category theory was invented in part to explain this in a precise way. So the explanation above is cheating a little bit by skipping over the story up to that point :) I recommend reading [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/579739/29335) which explains the situation better!

I don't rightly know if you can say "you don't need to choose a basis" to prove it, but you can certainly show that the result is "independent of basis" meaning that any selection is as good as another and the selection itself is immaterial.  Said another way, the isomorphism you come up with is the same no matter which basis you select.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. Your comment on the isomorphism proof not depending on the selection of basis, rather than it not requiring a basis at all, is very useful for me. The paragraph about functors went over my head unfortunately since I don't have advanced mathematical knowledge :(

Comment: @ShirishKulhari I know, this is NOT the way you explain it to someone the first time they're seeing it.  Actually, I need to explain something a little further with a link to a better post...

Comment: Part of the reason I wrote this is so that I'd have something to refer back to with this explanation. I think I saw elsewhere where someone claimed that this "natural isomorphism" really didn't have anything to do with category theory, that it was just a coincidence. Not finding that post, I recorded an answer here.