# How does $W \subset W^{00}$ ? Hoffman and Kunze theorem 3.18

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, proof-explanation, dual-spaces, vector-space-isomorphism

> **Hoffman and Kunze theorem 3.18** . If $S$ is any subset of a finite-dimensional vector space $V$,
> then $(S^0)^0$ is the subspace spanned by $S$.

> $S^0$ is the annihilator of $S$ and $S^{00}$ is  annihilator of $S^0
> $

if $W$ is the subspace spanned by $S$ then the book stated that $W \subset W^{00}$ and so $W=W^{00}$

But how is this true ? if $V^{*} $ is a dual for $V$ and $V^{* *}$ is a dual for $V^{*}$ then $W^{00}$ should be in $V^{* *}$ not $V$ , I know that there is an isomorphism from $V$ to $V^{* *}$ but what does that have to do with this theorem?

Comment: Perhaps do you care to explain the meaning of the notation $S^0$? Is it the [annihilator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_space#Quotient_spaces_and_annihilators) of $S$? Also, I guess that they are using the natural isomorphism between $V$ and $V^{**}$ to identify those two spaces.

Comment: @SangchulLee yes it is , I thought is is a universal notation like $\int$

Comment: @SangchulLee yeah but how is $W \subset W^{00}$ ? the vector space $R^6$ is isomorphic to the space consist of $3\times 2$ matrices , does that mean that a subspace of $R^6$ is a subset of the space consist of $3\times 2$ matrices? for example the set of $all (x_1,x_2,0,0,0,0)$ will make a subspace of $R^6$ but it doesn't belong to the space consist of $3\times 2$ matrices


So I don't understand how isomorphism plays a role here

Comment: Indeed, $V$ and $V^{**}$ are not the same as sets, so the "inclusion" must be properly reworded in the context of "identification via isomorphism" if one needs full rigor. However, there is one excuse for this exploitation. Unlike other isomorphisms such as you mentioned, the isomorphism between a finite-dimensional vector space $V$ and its double dual $V^{**}$ is [*naturally isomorphic*](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4261719/). This in particular means that it is meaningless to distinguish $V$ and $V^{**}$ in the category of finite-dimensional vector spaces.

Comment: To give an analogy, here is another example in which different objects are identified for being naturally isomorphic: Let $A_1, A_2, A_3$ be sets, and let $[3]=\{1,2,3\}$. Then $$A_1\times(A_2\times A_3), \qquad (A_1\times A_2)\times A_3, \qquad \prod_{i\in[3]}A_i$$ are all different as sets, but they are naturally isomorphic as sets, representing the set of all triples $(a_1,a_2,a_3)$ where $a_i\in A_i$ for each $i$. So, we often treat them as identical and use them interchangeably.

Comment: Equivalently, you can consider the "pre-annihilator" of a subset of a dual space. For $T \subseteq V^*$, define $T_0 = \{v \in V : \forall t \in T (t(v) = 0)\}$. Then $S = (S^0)_0$ is literally true, and the image of $(S^0)_0$ in $V^{**}$ is precisely $S^{00}$ (here assuming $V$ is finite-dimensional).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by @Sangchul Lee the finite dimensional vector space $V$ over the field $\mathbb{F}$ is naturally isomorphic with its double dual $V^{\ast \ast}.$ The isomorphism is the map that takes $v\in V$ to the evaluation of a functional at $v$, i.e. $v \mapsto v^{\ast\ast}$ with $v^{\ast\ast}(f) = f(v)$ for all $f \in V^\ast.$

Let $S$ be a subset of $V$ and $W = \text{span}(S)$ the subspace of $V$ generated by $S.$ Note that $S^\circ \subseteq V^\ast$ is the set of functionals $f\colon V \to \mathbb{F}$ that vanish on $S$, i.e. $f(s) = 0$ for all $s \in S.$ By linearity of $f$, this also means that $f(w) = 0$ for all $w \in W.$ The double polar $S^{\circ\circ} \subset V^{\ast\ast}$ is the set of all functionals $\phi \colon V^\ast \to \mathbb{F}$ that vanish on $S^\circ,$ that is $\phi(f) = 0$ for all $f \in S^\circ.$ By the natural isomorphism, we can see $S^{\circ \circ} \subseteq V^{\ast\ast} \cong V$ as a set of elements $v$ for which the evaluation at $v$ of a fucntional $f \in S^\circ$ is $0$, i.e. $v^{\ast\ast}(f) = f(v) = 0$ for all $f \in S^\circ.$

Now let us proof that $W = S^{\circ\circ}.$ Let therefore $\{s_1,\dots,s_n\}$ be a basis for $W$ and complete it to $\{s_1, \dots, s_n,r_1,\dots, r_m\}$ to yield a basis for $V$ with $s_i \in S, i =1,\dots,n$ and $r_j\in V \setminus S, j = 1,\dots, m.$

If $v \in W$, then we can uniquely write $v = a_1s_1 + \dots + a_n s_n$ for some $a_i \in \mathbb{F}.$ We see this $v$ as the element $v^{\ast \ast} \in V^{\ast \ast}.$ Then for any $f \in S^{\circ},$ we know $\left. f\right|_S = 0$, therefore, by linearity of $f$ we have $$ v^{\ast\ast}(f) = f(v) = 0,$$ and hence $v^{\ast \ast} \in S^{\circ\circ}.$ Using the identification we write $W \subset S^{\circ\circ}.$

For the other direction. Consider the functionals $f_j \colon V \to \mathbb{F}$ given by

$$
f_j(v) = b_j, \quad \text{ if } v = a_1 s_1 + \dots + a_ns_n + b_1 r_1 + \dots + b_m r_m
$$

note that the decomposition of this $v$ is unique. Then $f_j \in S^\circ$ for $j=1,\dots, m$ follows. Now let $\phi \in S^{\circ\circ}$ be arbitrary and use the isomorphism to write $\phi = v^{\ast \ast}$ for some $v \in V.$ Note that $\phi$ vanishes on $S^\circ.$ This means $v^{\ast\ast}(f) = \phi(f) = 0$ for $f \in S^\circ.$ We  now show that $v$ lies in $W.$ Decomposing $v = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i s_i + \sum_{j=1}^m b_j r_j,$ then yields that $v^{\ast\ast}(f_j)=f_j(v)=b_j =0$ for all $j$ as $f_j \in S^{\circ}$ and hence $v \in W.$ We conclude $S^{\circ \circ} \subset W$ (under the isomorphism).

I hope it helps a bit, there might be a shorter argument.