# Is there a natural isomorphism between $V$ and its dual $V'$?

Tags: linear-algebra, dual-spaces

I'm aware of the fact that there exists a natural isomorphism between a vector space $V$ and its double dual $V''$; what I'm asking is the following: let's define an application $F:V\to V'$ as $F(v)=v^T$ (the image of a vector is the application of the dual which corresponds to multiplying to the transpose of said vector); now for every $v\in V$ we can find $F(v)\in V'$ and vice versa, therefore $F$ is an isomorphism. Now I believe that could be considered a natural isomorphism since whatever are the basis for $V$ and $V'$, the coordinates of some vector with respect to said basis are unique and therefore to one vector in $V$ with respect to some basis $\mathscr{B}_V$ corresponds one and only application in $V'$ with respect to some basis $\mathscr{B}_{V'}$, even if $\mathscr{B}_{V'}$ is not the dual basis of $\mathscr{B}_V$.

Why isn't this a natural isomorphism? It seems to me I don't need to chose a basis for either $V$ or its dual in order to make this work...

Comment: The transpose is not defined in an arbitrary vector space.

Comment: As a complement to @MikhailKatz's answer, what you describe works for instance in finite-dimensional spaces where indeed the space and its dual are isomorphic, and in Hilbert spaces where this shows that the space and a subspace of its dual (the continuous linear functionals only) are isomorphic.

Comment: @Beleth, finite-dimensional spaces are isomorphic to their duals as you say, but they are not *naturally* isomorphic to their duals.

Comment: @MikhailKatz yeah, right; didn't consider that, thanks!

Comment: @MikhailKatz you are right, I understood the use of "natural" as "that is rather simple and intuitive", and not as the mathematical definition of a natural isomorphism. Thanks for the precision.

Comment: Ah, you must be French :-) "Precision" in English does not mean précision.  English translation of the latter is "clarification".  @Beleth

Comment: no, there isn't.

Comment: @MikhailKatz You got me Sherlock, thank you for the clarification :) Best wishes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're stil not convinced by the non-naturality of transposition, you'll surely agree on something more geometric, that there's no natural *inner product*.

Or even simpler, there's no natural *length* (norm) defined on all vectors in all spaces - doubling any length (norm) makes it a just as valid norm.

But any identification between $U$ and its dual $U^*$, $\eta:U\to U^*$ defines a scalar product on $U$ $$\langle u,v\rangle = \eta(u)(v).$$

If there was a natural isomorphism between $U$ and $U^*$, that would automatically define a scalar product and hence a norm (length) by $\|u\|=\sqrt{\langle u,u\rangle}$, i.e. turn all vector spaces into inner product spaces, which they initially are not :)

Comment: The answers in the "Related" tab give some more rigorous treatment on this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/579739/why-it-is-important-for-isomorphism-between-vector-space-and-its-double-dual-spa?rq=1 https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/622589/in-categorical-terms-why-is-there-no-canonical-isomorphism-from-a-finite-dimens?rq=1

Comment: that's very clear, thank you!